# Can Kubernetes load images from Docker's local storage?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

As in the title: can I specify e.g.

```
image: frontend:3.4
```

in k8s' configuration file without giving any reference to local repository/Docker Hub/any other remote registry?

In other words: can Kubernetes load local images like Docker does, e.g.:

```
docker --rm --name frontend frontend:3.4
```

Comment: What do you use as kubernetes cluster?

Comment: @Thomas: microk8s on ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Microk8s you need to import the image first, so direct access to the docker daemon is not possible.

For example you have your local image `frontend:3.4` you need to export it from docker and import it like so:

```
docker save frontend:3.4 > tmp-image.tar
microk8s ctr image import tmp-image.tar
```

You can verify the import using

```
microk8s ctr images ls
```

Comment: Please add to the answer that the image has to be referenced by the `REF` output by `microk8s ctr images ls` command and the whole entry will probably look similar to `image: docker.io/library/frontend:3.4`.

Comment: The prefix `docker.io/library` is added by container engines if no registry (docker.io) or repository (library) was specified, like the `:latest` tag if no tag was supplied. It should work as stated in the answer, but a fully qualified image can be used interchangeably.